# Why does Mathematica constantly reevaluate an expression?

Tags: manipulate, random

```
Manipulate[
  f[n_] := 1/n^2; 
  pt = Accumulate[Table[Table[f[i], {i, max}][[n]], 
          {n, PermutationReplace[Table[i, {i, max}], RandomPermutation[max]]}]]; 

  DiscretePlot[pt[[n]], {n, 1, max}],

  {{max, 5}, 2, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

  Deployed -> True]
```

The problem is that Mathematica constantly reevaluates the randomization. Even if the mouse is completely outside the `Manipulate`, the plot constantly flashes and changes.

But now here goes the really weird part. If the whole `Manipulate` gets a bit less complex... this behaviour ceases.

```
Manipulate[
  pt = Accumulate[PermutationReplace[Table[i, {i, 1, max}], 
          RandomPermutation[max]]]; 

  DiscretePlot[pt[[n]], {n, 1, max}], 

  {{max, 5}, 2, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Deployed -> True]
```

Everything looks nicely here. Yes, it does seem Mathematica re-randomizes this two or three Times too often, so it takes a second for the plot to calm down and stop changing; but after that time, everything looks well.

How to fix this? And why does this happen?

PS. Sorry for spamming the site... I really need to have a better knowledge of Mathematica, I know. But, for my defence, this really seems weird and unandersandable.

Comment: Move the function definition outside the manipulate.

Comment: @bills Can't believe it, works! Finally stopped this bizzare blinking. Thanks! But, could you elaborate this a little bit more? I'd be very grateful if you made me understand was was actually going on :)

Comment: Best to use the `Initialization` option to initialize the function rather than have it in the body as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulate updates each time its expression changes. The expression is a function of the control variables. Or if the expression contains a symbol or expression that appears only inside the Manipulate expression (i.e. not global before), even though it is not control variable, and this symbol/expression gets updated during evaluation of the manipulate expression.

In your  example below, we see these symbols `f[],n,i,max,pt`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The control variable is `max`, so when `max` changes, `pt` changes. The symbols `i,n` are local to `Table` by definition, hence they do not affect the update.

So what is left is `f[]`. Notice that when `pt` changes, inside the `Table` you are calling `f[i]`, then `Table` will make repeated evaluation for each Table index See

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationInIterationFunctions.html

To solve this, you make make a module inside Manipulate, and define any symbols used in the expression, which are not control variable, in the module, like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{f, n, i},
  f[n_] := 1/n^2;
  pt = Accumulate[
    Table[
     Table[Evaluate@f[i], {i, max}][[n]], {n, PermutationReplace[Table[i, 
        {i, max}], RandomPermutation[max]]}]
    ];
  DiscretePlot[pt[[n]], {n, 1, max}]
  ],
 {{max, 5}, 2, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Deployed -> True]
```

Another way to solve this, which is what I prefer to do, is to use `TrackedSymbols`.

```
 Manipulate[
 f[n_] := 1/n^2;
 pt = Accumulate[
   Table[
    Table[f[i], {i, max}][[n]], {n, PermutationReplace[Table[i, {i, max}],
       RandomPermutation[max]]}]
   ];
 DiscretePlot[pt[[n]], {n, 1, max}],
 {{max, 5}, 2, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {max},
 Deployed -> True]
```

Here is a simple example that shows the problem you were having

```
Manipulate[
 g[n_] := n;
 Table[g[i], {i, 1, max}],
 {{max, 10, "max"}, 1, 10, 1}
 ]
```

This will now re-evaluate repeatedly.

Comment: Many thanks, it works! One last question. Why: `TrackedSymbols:>{max}`, and not: `TrackedSymbols->{max}`? Why do we have to have here a `RuleDelayed` rather then a normal `Rule`?

Comment: From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html  `Using Rule for TrackedSymbols fails in some cases because the symbols are evaluated` That is why delayed in this case is always used. `Generally, RuleDelayed should always be used for TrackedSymbols:`  This is very important. Always use :> with trackedsymbols. I once spent whole day trying to figure what I was doing wrong, then at the end I noticed I used `->` instead of `:>`