# Why does Mathematica stay on an endless evaluating loop with Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, scoping, finance

I have built Manipulate to see the impact of a change in time and volatility to the profit of an option strategy, bull spread.
To calculate the price of the option, I built the good old Black-Scholes:

```
optionValue[s0_, x_, t_, sigmasq_, rf_] := Module[{d1, d2},
d1 = (Log[s0/x] + (rf + sigmasq/2) t)/Sqrt[sigmasq t];
d2 = d1 - Sqrt[sigmasq t];
s0 CDF[NormalDistribution[], d1] - x Exp[-rf t] CDF[NormalDistribution[], d2]]
```

Then I call the `optionValue` function with

```
premiumLongCall[time_,volatility_]:=optionValue[250,230,time,volatility,0];
premiumShortCall[time_,volatility_]:=optionValue[250,270,time,volatility,0];
```

Finally, I build the Manipulate so I can plot the profit of the strategy and the profit for each option by itself with the ability to change time and volatility:

```
Manipulate[
 premiumLong = premiumLongCall[tic, vol];
 premiumShort = premiumShortCall[tic, vol];

 option11[stockPrice_ /; stockPrice > 230] := 
  stockPrice - 230 - premiumLong;
 option11[stockPrice_] := -premiumLong;
 option22[stockPrice_ /; stockPrice > 270] := 
  270 - stockPrice + premiumShort;
 option22[stockPrice_] := premiumShort;

 Plot[{option11[s] + option22[s], option11[s], option22[s]}, {s, 170, 
   320}, PlotLabel -> "Bull spread", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Stock price", "Profit"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Total profit", "Long call profit", 
    "Short call profit"}, PlotTheme -> "Working", 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed, Dashed}], {{tic, 0.5}, {0.5, 
   5/12}}, {{vol, 0.35}, {0.35, 0.2625}}]
```

I get the plot but Mathematica enters into an eternal loop.

I checked this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71686/why-does-mathematica-constantly-reevaluate-an-expression/) but I am having trouble relocating the functions outside of Manipulate while keeping `tic` and `vol` inside.

I have also tried using Module like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80323/module-and-manipulate-why-the-red-highlighting/80324#80324) but then my plot looks incomplete.

Please let me know how to best redesign this code to stop the endless evaluation loop.

Thanks in advance,
Thad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `TrackedSymbols :> {tic, vol}` to `Manipulate`'s options helps a lot.